# Locating files conditional on file names in python

Tags: python, arcpy

I have several folders that have either a.shp or b.shp, plus some other miscellaneous files. Or, One folder can contain both a.shp and b.shp. In that case, I want to choose a.shp. If a folder does not have the two files, I exclude that folder from my analysis.

I have to write a python code something like the following:

```
 if folder1 has a.shp only:
    myunit = r"D:\folder1\a.shp"
 elif folder2 has b.shp only:
    myunit = r"D:\folder2\b.shp"
 elif folder3 has a.shp and b.shp:
    myunit = r"D:\folder3\a.shp"
 elif folder4 doesn't have a.shp and b.shp:
    Don't assign anything into myunit.
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could provide advice on how to do that in Python.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your code is not consistent with the description of your problem.
I am assuming that the problem is described correctly, so I created a function that filters the dirs that you need:

```
import os

def filter_dirs(dirs=[]):
    result = []
    for dir in dirs:
        files = os.listdir(dir)
        file_a = 'a.shp' in files
        file_b = 'b.shp' in files
        if file_a or file_b:
            result.append({'dir':dir, 'file_a':file_a, 'file_b':file_b})
    return result
```

Then try the function with some folders and see the results:

```
filter_dirs(['D:\folder1', 'D:\folder2', 'D:\folder3'])
```

Comment: I've got the following error message: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'push'. However, replacing "push" with "append" worked. Thank you.

Comment: Ouch, you are right. I didn't tested the code on the console. Now it is fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you want `os.path.exists`, which takes a pathname as argument and returns `True` or `False` depending on whether it's the name of a file (or directory) that exists. You'll probably also want `os.path.join` for constructing filenames.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid importing os.path.exists and such, you could just use try/catch logic. If a's there you always want it, so you can try just opening it. If that doesn't work, catch the error and try opening b. If that doesn't work, catch the error and ignore that folder.

A code snippet from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/howto/doanddont.html) (ctrl+f for "Exceptions") showing the recommended way to do this:

```
def get_status(file):
    try:
        return open(file).readline()
    except EnvironmentError as err:
        print "Unable to open file: {}".format(err)
        sys.exit(1)
```

Also from the docs, a snippet showing the other way with os.path as Gareth describes:

```
def get_status(file):
    if not os.path.exists(file):
        print "file not found"
        sys.exit(1)
    return open(file).readline()
```

But the docs quote this to recommend against it on style grounds. Python deliberately has elegant exception handling; it's considered more idiomatic to take advantage of this than to worry about C-style paranoid checking of everything before you do it. If you want to do it the os.path way, though, do whatever. Works either way.